# Is query executed when mysql server has gone away?

Tags: mysql

How can I be sure that a query was not executed?

For example, I try to execute

```
update `table` set `a`='b'
```

and got the error `2006 server has gone away`

Comment: If you're worried about this, use transactions.

Comment: SELECT 
 COUNT(DISTINCT `a`),
 COUNT(*)
FROM `table`;
to determine current DISTINCT number of values in your a column and total row count

Answer (score 1):

Don't run the SQL statement :-)

If you want the mysql client to stop you running it, there is a `--safe-updates` aka `--i-am-a-dummy` option.

If you want the server to rollback, use innodb tables that provide transactional support.

For the error see [gone away](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I be sure that a query was not executed?

It *did* execute and it *broke* your database in doing so!

As such, when you next start your database, it will perform an "Instance Recovery" and *undo* any changes that were not committed at the point the instance died.

Once *that* is complete then it will be as if the query never ran - the database will have "undone" everything that the query did (to it!).